# browser-cache refresh through network

Tags: networking, browser-cache

We currently have "web-based" software running on several PC's in our network.

A problem we have run in a few times is that whenever the software is updated each PC has to refresh it's Browser Cache to prevent errors. Sadly most people on the network kinda neglect this leading to mishaps.

Is there a way to force a browser case refresh on all the PC's through the network?

Comment: This is something the "web-based software" developers should deal with. A website/web app can certainly be built to refresh/disregard its own cache when needed.

Comment: @YisroelTech Sadly, we aren't the ones developing it so that's not an option :|

Comment: But did you at least try to report to/ask the devs of it? I can't see how it should be possible to reset remote computers browser cache in any normal way.

Comment: @YisroelTech reported and ignored. That's why i came here.